# Empty Request body on express app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

When trying to make a POST call to an express.js server the body is empty.

I'm using react and express, so I've had to enable CORS to allow the calls from different servers. The code is as follows:

**Express**

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(), 
bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
cors = require("cors");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors()); 

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    console.log(req); 
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("test started"); 
})
```

**React**

```
handleSubmit(event){
    console.log(this.state); 
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
        body: {
            username: "asd",
            password: "asdd",
            }
    });
    event.preventDefault(); 
}
```

What am I missing here? I have done it with `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` and the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing to tell to your Express server that you will to use JSON. To accomplish that, you need to add this line before defining any route:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Besides that you need to `JSON.stringify` the body payload in your React's component `handleSubmit` method, because as it is right now, it is not JSON valid.

And finally the proper header you have to set is:

```
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Thus you tell the server you are sending a JSON body payload.

Comment: Body is still empty after adding that line before `app.use(cors());`

Comment: You need to `JSON.stringify` the body payload in your React's component `handleSubmit` method, because as it is right now, it is not JSON valid.

Comment: I also tried that already like: `body: JSON.stringify({
                username: "asd",
                password: "asdd",
              })` but same empty body.

Comment: There is still one more error. You need to set the proper header: `Content-Type`.

Comment: That fixed it! I had Content-Type at first, but removed it when trying out different stuff, seems like the problem was the missing `app.use(bodyParser.json());`. However I made another express application that didn't have this and was able to run well, so I'm confused as to why it didn't work this time.